# Etimologia do verbo "trepar"

Tags: etimologia

Qual a origem etimológica do verbo *trepar*? É a mesma de *trabalho*, do latim *trepalium* (‘tortura’)?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trepar#Etymology_2

Answer (score 1):

Não encontrei ninguém a sugerir que *trepar* viesse de *trepalium*. A visão dominante divide-se entre origem onomatopaica nas línguas latinas ou origem germânica, possivelmente também onomatopaica. Cito o dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002; desabrevio as abreviações):

> **trepar** […] ETIMOLOGIA provavelmente da onomatopeia *trip* imitativa do acto de pisar; segundo Corominas ao comentar o verbo espanhol *trepar* (sXV) ‘idem’, a onomatopeia *trip* ou *trep-*, que sugere o ruído de pisar, é a mesma que vai dar origem aos verbos *trepar* em catalão antigo e provençal e ao francês *triper* ou *treper;* a mesma onomatopeia encontra-se igualmente nas línguas germânicas, facto que não permite afirmar se ela seria empréstimo germânico às línguas latinas ou se seria criação paralela das duas famílias linguísticas.

O [dicionário da Real Academia Española](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aak99HW%7CaakcQON) diz simplesmente que *trepar*, que em espanhol partilha os significados primários do verbo português, é de origem onomatopaica. Mas o filólogo brasileiro Antenor Nascentes, apoiando-se em vários etimologistas diz que *trepar* vem do germânico *trippon*, que significava ‘pular’ [(*Dicionário Etimológico da Língua Portuguesa*, 1955, p. 504)](https://archive.org/stream/AntenorNascentesDicionaroEtimologicoDaLinguaPortuguesaTomoI/DicionarioEtimolgicoDaLinguaPortuguesa#page/n543/mode/2up)

É essa também a visão do [Centre National de Ressources Textuelles et Lexicales](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/tr%C3%A9pigner) relativamente ao antigo verbo francês *treper* (modernamente existe apenas o seu descendente *trépigner*, com significado parecido). Dizem eles que *treper*  já existia por volta de 1160, com o significado ‘bater com os pés, saltar’; e que veio do germânico *trippôn*, que significava ‘saltar’; descendem também desse verbo o baixo alemão *trippen*, o alemão moderno *trippeln* e o holandês *trippelen*, todos significando ‘andar com passos curtos e rápidos’.

É curioso que no Minho, Portugal, *trepar* tem também, à semelhança do francês antigo *treper*, o significado ‘calcar com os pés, pisar’ [(Priberam)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/trepar).

O verbo ingês *trip* tem a mesma origem. Diz o [Etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/trip) que *trip* aprece no século XIV, vindo do francês *triper*, que era um variante de *treper* (ver [Wikitionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/triper)). Originalmente o significado de *trip* era semelhante ao do francês *treper*, desenvolvendo-se os outros sentidos mais tarde.

As primeiras ocorrências que consegui encontrar dos verbos espanhol e português *trepar*, ambas do século XV, já tinham o significado atual. Aqui está, da *Crónica de D. João I* (1443) de Fernão Lopes ([Corpo Informatizado do Português Medieval](http://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/); negrito meu):

> COMO EL REY CHEGUOU A ÇIDADE DO PORTO E FOY REÇEBIDO DOS DO LOGUAR.
>
> [...]
>
> em çertos logarees avia bamdos de molheres que camtavaõ muitas cantigas, e **cordas armadas pera treparẽ homeẽs** que ho bem fazer sabiaõ, quamdo el Rey alo cheguase